# CSS/JQuery/Angular transition on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I ran into this beautiful UI mockup on Behance and am very curious about the best way to implement this.

https://www.behance.net/gallery/25264659/Google-transitions

Essentially, I would like my search bar and logo to animate up to the top exactly like this after the form (aka the text input) has been submitted.

My app is an Angular app, so would it be more practical to create an Angular directive? Or implement this with pure CSS or JQuery (independent from Angular)?

Comment: this question is too vague. not sure about angular, but with jquery and css you would use a series of animates, keyframes and css scale. I am sure there is an angularjs way to do it aswell but you would still use css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation will be independent of AngularJS. In regards to performance of the animation JQuery is by far the absolute slowest. The standard would be to use CSS transitions / animations. If you are not comfortable with CSS then user something like velocity.js. It has a syntax similar to JQuery but used window.requestAnimationFrame making it potentially even faster then CSS.

All Angular would be used for would be used for would be to call the animation or add / remove a class to cause the CSS transition to animation when the search is underway.

As for the animation itself I unfortunately cannot help much with, those things tend to take a lot of effort to get looking good.